# add a formula when a row is added vba

Tags: vba, excel-formula, addition, rows

I want to add the following formula in columns L to R when a row is added. So far this is what I have.

But I can't seem to figure out how to ensure that this macro ONLY occurs when a row is added and I don't want it to run to the last row but only for the newest row added.
Can anyone help me with this. I'm still new with VBA and although I looked around how to do this I was not able to capture the information that would help me add this formula on added rows only.
Thank you for your help

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To LastRow

        Range("L" & i).Value = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-8],RC[-7],Holidays)"
        Range("M" & i).Value = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-8],RC[-7],Holidays)"
        Range("N" & i).Value = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-8],RC[-7],Holidays)"
        Range("O" & i).Value = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-8],RC[-7],Holidays)"
        Range("P" & i).Value = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-8],RC[-7],Holidays)"
        Range("Q" & i).Value = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-8],RC[-7],Holidays)"
        Range("R" & i).Value = "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-8],RC[-7],Holidays)"
Next      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this off the top of my head (and probably others).

---

Test the `Target` range to see if its `Address` is a complete row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim test As Range
    Set test = Target.EntireRow
    If test.Address = Target.Address Then
        Debug.Print "Entire row changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Test the column count of the `Target` range to see if it contains every column:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count = Me.Columns.Count Then
        Debug.Print "Entire row changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Manually track the last row and compare against the cached value:

```
Private previousBottom As Long   '<--Worksheet level variable.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim bottom As Long
    bottom = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If bottom <> previousBottom Then
        previousBottom = bottom
        Debug.Print "Row inserted or deleted."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the first one and the last one and I added my code afterwards but nothing happens. Am I missing something? Note, I added the Next at the end of my code.

Comment: @ValS - The code that you want to run when an entire row is changed would go inside of the `If` blocks - just replace the line starting with `Debug.Print`.